# How to speed up the sparse matrix multiplication when using Eigen?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

I need to use Eigen to do some huge sparse matrices multiplication or addition/subtraction. It is much slower than using MATLAB for some cases. For example, for the following code

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> JPSlice = JP.block(0, 3, JP.rows(), JP.cols()-3);
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> NonZeroJD = RemoveSpMatrixZeroCols(JD);
JPSlice.makeCompressed();
NonZeroJD.makeCompressed();
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> U = JPSlice.transpose() * JPSlice;
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> V = NonZeroJD.transpose() * NonZeroJD;
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> InvV = InverseDiagonalSpMatrix(V);
InvV.makeCompressed();
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> VM1 = JPSlice.transpose() * NonZeroJD;
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Block = VM1 * InvV;
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> VM = Block * VM1.transpose();
```

The dimensions of JPSlice and NonZeroJD are 26400000 x 801 and $26400000 x 529530.

When using Eigen, the time consumed to compute VM1 and VM are 5.8s and 25s, while MATLAB only take around 0.8s and 0.7s. But the time consumption of calculation of V is similar between Eigen and MATLAB (around 3s).

I'm compiling this code on a Mac(with Clang and CMake) with the following compiler settings

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -march=native -mavx -mfma -fopenmp-simd -fopenmp=libomp -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL")
```

How to spped up these sparse matrices computation? Why is there such a big difference in computation speed between Eigen and C++?

Comment: If `InvV` is actually a diagonal, try just storing the coefficients in a vector `Eigen::VectorXd InvVdiag;` and do `VM1 * InvVdiag.asDiagonal() * VM1.transpose()` (unless you need the `Block` result as well). For `JPSlice.transpose()` it might be worth to store that into a temporary.

Comment: @chtz Thanks. I use InvVdiag.asDiagonal() to instead of InvV, now the time consumption of VM is around 21s. It improves the speed a bit, but it's still a far cry from MATLAB's computation time.

Comment: Is `JP` a dense matrix or sparse? How many nonzeros are there and do they have some pattern like block-diagonal?

Comment: @Homer512 Yes, JP is sparse matrix and each row has 3 non-zero elements. It does not has other pattern except the number of non-zero elements  for each row.